# Grafana loki - Bigtable - Requested column family not found

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, grafana, google-cloud-bigtable, grafana-loki

I installed Loki distributed helm chart in my GKE cluster which uses GCS and Bigtable.
When I check loki ingester pod, I have following error:

> level=error ts=2023-01-06T13:01:59.107018356Z caller=flush.go:146 org_id=fake msg="failed to flush user" err="store put chunk: rpc error: code = NotFound desc = Error while mutating the row '08:fake:d19362:logs' (projects//instances/mybigtable/tables/loki_index_2766) : Requested column family not found.

I have followed the docs https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/upgrading/#240, accordingly prepared the configmap. Here is the file:

```
---
# Source: loki-distributed/templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: loki-loki-distributed
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: loki-distributed-0.67.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: loki-distributed
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: loki
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.6.1"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
data:
  config.yaml: |
    auth_enabled: false
    chunk_store_config: 
      max_look_back_period: 672h
    compactor:
      retention_enabled: true
      shared_store: filesystem
    distributor:
      ring:
        kvstore:
          store: memberlist
    frontend:
      compress_responses: true
      log_queries_longer_than: 5s
      tail_proxy_url: http://loki-loki-distributed-querier:3100
    frontend_worker:
      frontend_address: loki-loki-distributed-query-frontend:9095
    ingester:
      chunk_block_size: 262144
      chunk_encoding: snappy
      chunk_idle_period: 30m
      chunk_retain_period: 1m
      lifecycler:
        ring:
          kvstore:
            store: memberlist
          replication_factor: 1
      max_transfer_retries: 0
      wal:
        dir: /var/loki/wal
    limits_config:
      enforce_metric_name: false
      retention_period: 30d
      max_cache_freshness_per_query: 10m
      reject_old_samples: true
      reject_old_samples_max_age: 168h
      split_queries_by_interval: 15m
    memberlist:
      join_members:
      - loki-loki-distributed-memberlist
    query_range:
      align_queries_with_step: true
      cache_results: true
      max_retries: 5
      results_cache:
        cache:
          enable_fifocache: true
          fifocache:
            max_size_items: 1024
            ttl: 24h
    ruler:
      alertmanager_url: https://alertmanager.xx
      external_url: https://alertmanager.xx
      ring:
        kvstore:
          store: memberlist
      rule_path: /tmp/loki/scratch
      storage:
        local:
          directory: /etc/loki/rules
        type: local
    runtime_config:
      file: /var/loki-distributed-runtime/runtime.yaml
    schema_config:
      configs:
      - from: 2023-01-01
        store: bigtable
        object_store: gcs
        schema: v12
        index:
          prefix: loki_index_
          period: 168h

    server:
      http_listen_port: 3100
    storage_config:
      gcs:
        bucket_name: gcs-logs
      bigtable:
        instance: loki-indexes
        project: myproject-id
      boltdb_shipper:        
        active_index_directory: /loki/boltdb-shipper-active
        cache_location: /loki/boltdb-shipper-cache
        cache_ttl: 24h
        shared_store: gcs
        
        #active_index_directory: /var/loki/index
        #cache_location: /var/loki/cache
        #cache_ttl: 168h
        #shared_store: filesystem
      
      filesystem:
        directory: /var/loki/chunks
    table_manager:
      retention_deletes_enabled: true
      retention_period: 672h
```

I am not able to push log index to bigtable. It seems table_manager needs to be updated but not sure with what?

The loki distributed service account is annotated with IAM service account, for workload identity rights to push towards object stores.

```
---
# Source: loki-distributed/templates/serviceaccount.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: loki-loki-distributed
  labels:
    helm.sh/chart: loki-distributed-0.67.0
    app.kubernetes.io/name: loki-distributed
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: loki
    app.kubernetes.io/version: "2.6.1"
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: <iam-sa-account>@<project-id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com
automountServiceAccountToken: true
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Try to create additional family in the Bigtable table. Refer to this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55977811/import-of-avro-files-to-bigtable-error-with-family-not-found) it may help to resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks, but what would be the column family name? I added one, but I have the same error.

Comment: Check this similar [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70360571/bigtable-mutating-multiple-values-into-single-column-in-a-single-column-family) for more info.